# auto save in django list display mode

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-tools

here is my code for admin.py with a model named BASE2

```
class Base2Admin(ExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = Base2Resource
    filter_horizontal = ('images',)
    list_display = ('id', 'name','description','promoted', 'slug')
    search_fields=['name','description', 'slug']
    list_editable = ('name', 'description','promoted', 'slug')
```

so now i get list display of all my data but what i want is that in admin in list mode the data should get saved on every keystroke.   basically i do not want to click on the save button below

Comment: I'd say this is a purely template-related (not view-related) question. Add some javascript that will submit the form on every keystroke, if that is really what you want to do (unless it is done asynchronously via some AJAX, it's gonna be pretty unusable).

Comment: You wirte and add your own **javascript** to add (as @petr said) asynchronous functions.